# Table View Height restricted Scroll

Tags: swift, scroll, tableview

so I have a table view which is the right size of my screen but the height is wrong because I cann't scroll down to see more parts/cells.

I have set the height in this code:

```
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 75, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
```

should I just make the height a really big number or is there a way so that when more cells are filled I can scroll down?

Comment: Your TableView doesnt have same position as your view btw. TableView is 75 points from the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 75, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 75)
```

You have add y position at 75. so remove 75 from screen height.